# Easiest way to add upper Navigation bar and "back" buttons to UIViewController?

Tags: ios, interface-builder, uistoryboard

In my current storyboard file, there are lots of (about 150) view controllers that are `UIViewController` instances connected with segues, and now my client requested me to add a Navigation bar and "Back" button to every existing view controllers.

I found out that "just simply adding `UINavigationBar` to `UIViewController`s doesn't make results like the most views found in famous apps. In fact, the famous views seem to be built by `UINavigationController`, not `UIViewController`. So, probably replacing `UIViewController` to `UINavigationController` will solve.

But since there are 150 of them, it's a little too painful for me to replace all `UIViewController`s to `UINavigationController` manually. I should have built my storyboard file with `UINavigationController` from the first time, but it's too late.

Is it sure it's the only way? Aren't there any other ways, or some kind of  hack I can use to save my time?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen your code so I'm just probing the situation but I think your best bet would be to wrap your first ViewController in a NavigationController.

To do this easily, select your first view controller in your Storyboard and select: Menu -> Editor -> Embed In -> Navigation Controller.

All the descendants of that original ViewController should inherit the embedding.